# Lastools error: version major out of range

Tags: cloud, gis, point, lidar

I run `lasinfo` with a .las file and get the following error message.

```
$ lasinfo a.las
```

> error: version major out of range

I wonder what is the reason and how can I resolve it ?

Comment: I am sorry that I can't open it so still don't know the version or cut a piece off. I will check it on Monday an then tell you.

Comment: I checked the file. And I also read other sources las file with lastool. It works well. The file I mentioned here is a las file from Trimble's mobile surveying car. It's header:x?]g]@y]@b���D@TEMT3D_CAPTURE�-�BBQ\D@�}�lg,@N�[�a@LASF_X R8 LASF_Y R8 LASF_Z R8 LASF_INTENSITY R4 LASF_CLASSIFICATION UI1 LASF_POINT_SOURCE_ID UI2 LASF_ATTRIBUTES G3D_LATRANGE R4 G3D_RED UI1 G3D_GREEN UI1 G3D_BLUE UI1 G3D_CLASS_CONFIDENCE UI1 G3D_ANGLEH R4 G3D_ANGLEV R4 G3D_DISTANCE R4 G3D_DEVIATION R4 G3D_SCANSIZE50N,Default componentNo Comment in this componentS999882VQ-25~X

Answer (score 1):

Without knowledge of your version of lastools or the data in the file header, I can't say anything for sure about "why" the error is being thrown. I can hazard a guess that the las file version, as defined in the las header, is too high for your version of lastools, which may be doing bounds checking on those version values (my local version of lastools does not do any bounds checking that I can see, so I can't be sure that's the correct answer).

`version_major` in a .las header file must be "1" for all existing version of the las file format: http://www.asprs.org/Committee-General/LASer-LAS-File-Format-Exchange-Activities.html.

If you wanted to check the lasfile version as it is written in the las header, you can use the following python script (depends on `laspy`, install with `pip install laspy`):

```py
import laspy.file
lasfile = laspy.file.File("a.las")
print "File major version:", lasfile.header.version_major
print "File minor version:", lasfile.header.version_minor
```

As far as I can tell, `laspy` does not do any checks on that header version, so you should be able to use that script to check the advertised las version in your file.

With regards to fixing your problem, I don't know what you're trying to do with this lasfile, but if you're just looking to get information about it (as I might guess by your use of the `lasinfo` command) you could try:

- [libLAS](http://www.liblas.org/), use `lasinfo a.las`
- [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/), use `pdal info a.las`

Both of these software packages are free and open source, and can be installed via packages or from source on most major operating systems. I don't know if they would be happy reading a lasfile with an invalid `version_major`, but it would be worth a shot.

If your `version_major` really is invalid (e.g it is set to "2" or something weird like that), you could try resetting it with `laspy` or another software suite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! It was long time but you know we Chinese people can not go to the internet outside China easily. Thank you for your help. 
I found later that the .las file is from Trimble's mobile mapping vehicle. And Trimble is using their personalized version of .las file. It is why I can not read the .las file with lasinfo. Lasinfo works well with standard .las files.